# How do you pass an array to mergeWhen function in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have this code.

```
$this->mergeWhen($request->stats=='partner_count',
                 ['partner_count' => $this->partner_count])
```

Instead of `$request->stats=='partner_count'`, I want to pass an array of request values. Is it possible or not?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. As per the [Laravel Manual](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-resources) you can pass an array like this

```
$this->mergeWhen($this->isAdmin(), [
            'first-secret' => 'value',
            'second-secret' => 'value',
        ]),
```